# mvc model binding collections on forms, submit only changes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i've seen how to do model binding with asp mvc using collections of objects on a form. how does one submit only changes, a subset of the collection objects, that got changed? (add, delete, change). override the submit with script and somehow roll it yourself ? (to make it easy, lets make the granularity of changes restricted to an object in the collection, ie not down to the object properties).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider dropping the form altogether and just focus on posting json back to the server. This will save you a lot of fiddling with input elements.

On the server side you can just bind to a list of the given object.

Answer (score 0):

If you submit only changes, you will have to 
a. manually submit the form elements that have changed in either a manual jQuery call (either through submitting the data via jQuery via json or explicitly passing in the form values

```
$.post("/controller/action", { name1: "John", name2: "Mary" } );
```

its your design choice to use json or not here - both will work just fine.
if you choose json, change your dataType in the call to json you use

```
dataType: 'json'
```

b. remove the unchanged elements from the form upon post and 
c. move the changed elements into their own form before post
both b/c can use:

```
$.post("/controller/action", $("#changedForm").serialize());
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I got something going then later found a similar design here - http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Comment: to get changes for collections down to their properties, subscribe once to keypressed events on the input controls, handle the event by adding a 'changed' class on the target, then on save, select the changed items, clear the changed class, and serialize just those controls and submit (and resubscribe again to the changed controls). On the server,use AutoMap to merge the sparse incoming properties with the relevant database entries. I also added a collectionItem div to wrap one collection item, so that i can find the hidden input control that is needed to be submitted get model binding working

Comment: what was it on steves method that worked for you - that is a dynamic list, not just what changed. what was your final method you used?

Comment: I guess i used the ajax add and remove like in Steves post. but unlike his, i had to use an ajax submit and forego the form submit so i could detect changes and only serialize the changed properties. i created a simple object that does add/delete and change detection so that there is only a few extra lines of code needed in a 'form' to get this functionality. i can post it here if anyone wants it.